# quickly adding large numbers of mesh primitives in blender

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to add tens of thousands of mesh primitives to a scene in blender using its Python interface. I've been using something to the effect of:

```
for i in range(10000):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=(i, i, i))
```

This approach takes many minutes, though. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14846/935) compares the time of different ways to create multiple cubes. Using bmesh to create the cubes as one object would my first suggestion, but that depends on what you want to do, if they stay static then leave it as one object, you only need to separate them into multiple objects if you want to use them in a simulation. There are ways to animate them if they are one mesh object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector;

n = "cube";
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1);
orig_cube = bpy.context.active_object;

for i in range(10000):
    m = orig_cube.data.copy();
    o = bpy.data.objects.new(n, m);
    o.location = Vector((i, i, i));
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(o);

bpy.ops.object.delete();
```

Takes about 15 seconds on my machine. If you don't need to have unique cubes (i.e. don't intend to modify their geometry separately) then you can attach the same mesh to multiple objects. There are probably faster ways like creating single mesh and point cloud and using dupliverts (duplicating child object on each vertex of point cloud).

Example with just points and dupliverts (which, as expected, completes in a moment, but of course is not the same thing):

```
import bpy;
import bmesh;
from mathutils import Vector;

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1);
orig_cube = bpy.context.active_object;

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add();
o = bpy.context.active_object;
me = o.data;
bm = bmesh.new();
for i in range(10000):
    bm.verts.new().co=Vector((i, i, i));
bm.to_mesh(me);
o.dupli_type = 'VERTS';
orig_cube.parent = o;
```

Comment: Could you add something about how one might go about creating a point cloud quickly?

Comment: @paleto-fuera-de-madrid I've edited in an example. Also scripts bundled with blender are usually good examples.

Comment: Can you set a different color for each cube?